# Trying to run Windows from USB on Mac, says "No bootable device found"

Tags: windows, usb, startup

I am trying to run Windows 10 on my Macbook Air. I originally wanted to upgrade my SSD so that I would have enough space for a windows partition. Unfortunately, I can't do that with my model (I have a mid 2013 Macbook Air) so I'm trying to run Windows from a USB instead. I Downloaded the windows .iso, installed it on the flash drive using WinToUSB on a Windows computer and all appeared to be fine. I inserted the USB, restarted my computer, and chose to boot "Windows". Then a screen came up informing me that No bootable device was found and saying something about BIOS. I am at a total loss of what to do to make this work...

Comment: You can only boot into Windows on a Mac via Boot Camp.

Comment: You could move your OS X  to the USB to free up space to install Window 10 on your internal SSD. Or, move just your personal files to the USB. Could up update your question to include the model and/or year of your Macbook Air. Usually, people use the Boot Camp Assistant to create the installation flash drive. This is not the only way to install Windows 10, but it is the simplest.

Comment: I updated the question-- it's a mid 2013 Air. I think I may just end up moving my personal files over like you suggested. I initially wanted to maximize the amount of space I would have for files I create & programs I plan to run through Windows (so I wanted to run it from a 128GB usb), but it looks like I may be out of luck.